# AAM result in Server Error

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping

Created a new 2010 environment.

SP servername: sp2010 
FQDN: my.domain.com

Bindings have been set to

- http    sp2010    80
- http    my.domain.com    80

Before AAM changes:

- **sp2010** resolves
- **my.domain.com** gives blank page
- **localhost** resolves

When View Source on blank page, returns:

After setting AAM:

Internal URL          Public URL
my.domain.com     my.domain.com
sp2010                  my.domain.com

- **my.domain.com** gives a blank page
- **sp2010** redirects the URL to my.domain.com however page renders a 
  **Server Error in '/' Application**  
  HTTP 404 Requested URL: /SitesPages/Home.aspx

Anyone have any ideas why my.domain.com is not rendering?

Comment: check the DNS, if it is properly configured to that server(sp2010)? also in command prompt from your pc run tracert my.domain.com...check which server it is landing? if you accessing it from server try to acess it from pc

Comment: Good idea.  I just did a tracert and see it's pointing to the DC.  Not what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: thats it, your DNS is not pointing to correct wfe. please change it and test if it works let me know then i will add it as answer for other benifits and some points for me...:)

Comment: I created a an A record to DNS to point to the SP server (left Name field blank) and now everything works!  Thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: I added that as answer if you marked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run tracert from command prompt n see where it lands.

Looks like may be an issue with DNS. Check the A record if it is pointing to right Web front end.  Create an A record in DNS to point to the SP server (left Name field blank).

Answer (score 0):

I guess even though you added URL in AAM, you will need to also add IIS bindings for said URL.

To do IIS bindings:

1. Open Internet Information Servers (IIS) Manager on your Web Front End (WFE) and select your site. (This same action has to be done for each WFE)
2. On the far left panel you will see ‘Bindings…’.
3. Once the binding window is open for your SharePoint site click ‘Add…’. Enter your new URL into the ‘Host name:’ text box. (don’t add the ‘http://’)
4. Click OK.
5. Click Close.

And you are done from the IIS side.

For more information: http://www.techgrowingpains.com/2012/05/how-to-add-an-alternate-access-mapping-aam/

Comment: Bindings have been set.